# How can I render checkboxes based on dropdownlist value in my Pug index file using Node.js and Heroku server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, pug

I have the following index.pug file in my Node.js app hosted on Heroku:

```
extends layout

block content
  article.slds-card
    .slds-card__header.slds-grid
      header.slds-media.slds-media_center.slds-has-flexi-truncate
        .slds-media__figure
          span.slds-icon_container.slds-icon-standard-contact(title="contact")
            svg.slds-icon.slds-icon_small(aria-hidden="true")
              use(xlink:href="/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#contact")
            span.slds-assistive-text contact
        .slds-media__body
          h2.slds-card__header-title
            a.slds-card__header-link.slds-truncate(href="javascript:void(0);" title="Card Header")
              span= title
    .slds-card__body.slds-card__body_inner
      form.js-settings-form
        .slds-form-element
          label.slds-form-element__label(for="DropdownOptions") Target System
          .slds-form-element__control
            .slds-select_container
              select#DropdownOptions.slds-select.js-activity-setting(name='dropdownOptions')
                each dropdownOption in dropdownOptions
                  option(value=dropdownOption.value)= dropdownOption.name
```

in another directory of the app there is also an index.js file which looks like that and works just fine:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

/**
 * Render Config
 * @param req
 * @param res
 */
exports.config = (req, res) => {
  const domain = req.headers.host || req.headers.origin;
  const file = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'config-template.json');

  const configTemplate = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf-8');
  const config = JSON.parse(configTemplate.replace(/\$DOMAIN/g, domain));
  res.json(config);
};

/**
 * Render UI
 * @param req
 * @param res
 */
exports.ui = (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Custom Activity',
    dropdownOptions: [
      {
        name: 'Select target system',
        value: 'Select target system',
      },
      {
        name: '1',
        value: '1',
      },
      {
        name: '2',
        value: '2',
      },
    ],
  });
};
```

I am supposed to render different checkboxes on the index.pug file based on the value set in the dropdownlist (e.g. Checkbox1 if the value is equal to 1 and Checkbox2 + Checkbox3 if the value is equal to 2).

I tried to add a script on the index.pug file like this:

```
script.
            var dropdownOptions = document.getElementById('DropdownOptions');
            var checkboxContainer = document.createElement('div');
            checkboxContainer.id = 'checkboxContainer';
            document.querySelector('.js-settings-form').appendChild(checkboxContainer);
            dropdownOptions.addEventListener('change', function() {
              var selectedValue = dropdownOptions.value;
              checkboxContainer.innerHTML = '';
              if (selectedValue === '1') {
                label.slds-form-element__label.slds-p-top_medium(for='checkbox_1')
                  input.slds-checkbox(type='checkbox' id='checkbox_1' name='checkbox' value='1')
                  | 1
              } else if (selectedValue === '2') {
                  label.slds-form-element__label.slds-p-top_medium(for='checkbox_2')
                    input.slds-checkbox(type='checkbox' id='checkbox_2' name='checkbox' value='2')
                    | 2
                   label.slds-form-element__label.slds-p-top_medium(for='checkbox_3')
                    input.slds-checkbox(type='checkbox' id='checkbox_3' name='checkbox' value='3')
                    | 3
              }
            })
```

but I receive the error "Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: default-src self. Either the unsafe-inline keyword, a hash (sha256-AIxb3Bi5nSJSFRUcYj3Xyh+3aVfbCa7lsodeeETvYTY=), or a nonce (nonce-...) is required to enable inline execution. Note also that script-src was not explicitly set, so default-src is used as a fallback."

I also tried to call this same script in another script.js file in the same directory, but I received the following error: "Refused to execute script from 'https://mc-to-abc.herokuapp.com/routes/index.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.".

Thus I don't know how to proceed. Can anyone help?

Comment: In `pug`, the first one on every line (except those in a dotted block) is treated as a Html tag. So your `use(xlink:...)` will generate `<use xlink:...></use>`. Is this your intention?